# mysql UPDATE MAX value of group using MIN value of same group, multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to UPDATE the `open` value of MAX(id) of the group (`exchange, base_currency, quote_currency, DATE(created_at)`), using the value of MIN(id) of the same group.

```
id last open exchange base_curr quote_curr created_at

6  1.11 0.00 ex1      usd       yen        2018-07-29 03:00:00 --> update open with 1.09 (MIN(last) of group)          
5  1.09 0.00 ex1      usd       yen        2018-07-29 02:00:00
4  1.14 0.00 ex1      usd       yen        2018-07-29 01:00:00

3  0.49 0.00 ex2      yen       won        2018-07-29 03:00:00 --> update open with 0.49 (MIN(last) of group)
2  0.51 0.00 ex2      yen       won        2018-07-29 02:00:00
1  0.50 0.00 ex2      yen       won        2018-07-29 01:00:00
```

I know how to get all the MIN(id) of the groups, but not sure how to use those values to update the `open` value of MAX(id) of the group.

MAX(id) or MAX(created_at) would get me the latest rows of the groups.

```
SELECT MIN(id) as min_id, last
FROM tickers 
WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2018-07-29' 
GROUP BY exchange, base_currency, quote_currency, DATE(created_at)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
update tickers t join
       (select exchange, base_curr, quote_curr, date(created_at) as created_at_date,
               max(id) as maxid, min(last) as minlast
        from tickers t2
        group by exchange, base_curr, quote_curr, date(created_at)
       ) tt
       on tt.maxid = t.id
    set t.open = tt.minlast;
```